# Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated

Tags: php

the same error has propped up within these admincp files i am trying to set up on my server. how can i resolve them?

**Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\speedyautos\admincp\system_cls.php on line 152 (lines 152-155 shown)**

```
if (!eregi("install", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && !eregi("install", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))
                {
                                exit("No " . TABLE_PREFIX . "db.php Present. Please run Install first");
                }
```

**Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\speedyautos\admincp\system_cls.php on line 177 (lines 177-184 shown)**

```
if (!eregi("install", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && !eregi("install", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) && !eregi("upgrade", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) && !eregi("admincp", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && !eregi("searchjs.php", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && !eregi("locationjs.php", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
{
                register_shutdown_function("SysTime");
                if (!verifysession() && ($SystemInfo->_systemstatus['User_Signup'] != "F" || $SystemInfo->_systemstatus['Seller_Signup'] != "F" || $SystemInfo->_systemstatus['Dealer_Signup'] != "F"))
                {
                                eval("\$loginlink = \"" . $Template->gettemplate("register_link") . "\";");
                }
}
```

**Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\speedyautos\admincp\func.php on line 447 (lines 442-451 shown)**

```
if (!$GLOBALS['noshutdownfunc'])
                {
                                register_shutdown_function("CleanSessionTbl");
                }

} elseif (!eregi("install", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) AND !eregi("install", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))
{
                echo "Please delete the install.php file";
                exit;
}
```

many thanks in advance!

Comment: Canonical Question: [Converting ereg expressions to preg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you should use the [preg_*](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) family of regular expression matching. However, most of your `ereg` calls actually just search case insensitive. Instead of

```
!eregi("install", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
```

use

```
stripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'install') === false
```

. With [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), this would look like this:

```
!preg_match('/install/i', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `eregi("install", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` to `preg_match("/install/i", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`.

Answer (score 1):

Your concerns come a bit late. These functions have been deprecated since around PHP4. It's just the error messages which are new. If that's all you care about, then set `error_reporting()` or the `error_level` in the php.ini

You can convert almost any ereg() function into a preg_match() by simply adding some /regex/ delimiters. In your specific examples you can however just use `stripos()` by switching the arguments:

```
 stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "install")
```

Answer (score 1):

If that's all the regex you use with `eregi`, use `strpos`:

```
if (strpos($string_to_search_in, "install") === FALSE)  // Notice the three =
     echo("not found :(");
else
     echo("Found!");
```

If you use a more advanced regex you can do `strtolower` in the strings where you search in before the regexp's call.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code you're trying to use was designed for an older version of PHP.

Your best bet is going to be contacting the author and asking for a bug fix.

Failing that, if you're feeling adventurous and want to dive into the wonderful world of regexes, you can go through *every single file* and convert the `eregi` calls to [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) calls, taking into account [the different syntax that PCRE has compared to POSIX regular expressions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).  It looks like a few of these are abusing regexes, and can be replaced with more simple string matches, like [`stripos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).

If that seems like a bit much work, you can also [change the `error_reporting` level](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to exclude `E_DEPRECATED`.  You can do this at the script level, or at the PHP configuration level.  I'd recommend doing it at the script level -- chances are that there's a call to `error_reporting` somewhere in the init routines.